# Validating property using requiredif when dependent property is empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, unobtrusive-validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the following two properties in my model which are as follows:

```
[RequiredIf("WifiMAC==null", null, ErrorMessageResourceType = "Please enter GSMEthernetMAC")]
public string GSMEthernetMAC { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("GSMEthernetMAC==null", null, ErrorMessageResourceType = "Please enter WiFiMac")]
public string WifiMAC { get; set; }
```

The above code is working for `Null` but I want it to work for empty values too for condition such as "WiFi on Mac is empty/Null", then only `GSMEthernetMAC` should throw the validation message (i.e., "Please enter GSMEthernetMAC") and vice versa.

Please help me in getting this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using [MVC Foolproof Validation](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) or did you implement the RequiredIf yourself?

Comment: I used the existing one .I din't implement anything by myself.

Comment: Well... RequiredIf is not a native validation attribute in MVC and it depends on how you are going about doing it on how we could accomplish this. Are you perhaps using [Expressive Annotations](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) or some other third party library?

Comment: Thanks buddy !!
I am quite new to MVC . How far i know i am using only unobtrusive validation . Anyway if i have to go for empty value instead of null how could i achieve this ?

Comment: Assuming you are using foolproof validators, then it should be `[RequiredIfEmpty("WifiMAC", ErrorMessageResourceType = "..")]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke@br4d I can able to make it work . Actually i forgot to add the dependent js files for foolproof plugins . I am facing one more issue that is when i am navigating to that page from another page its not working but when i hit ctrl+f5 for the same page , it works like a charm. Can you please help me figure it out ?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing your controller code